# GREP: is there a way to use grep inserting a text between filename and the pattern?

Tags: shell, perl, unix, grep

I have `grep --color -EH "^([^,]*\,){3}5" try.csv`

and the output it does is this:

```
try.csv:410,30151010,K,5001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,512
try.csv:652,20151010,K,5001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,41
try.csv:109,30151010,R,5005,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,455
```

I tried `grep --color -EH "^([^,]*,){3}5" try.csv | perl -ne 'print ",$_"'`

but the output looks like this :

```
,try.csv:410,30151010,K,5001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,512
,try.csv:652,20151010,K,5001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,41
,try.csv:109,30151010,R,5005,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,455
```

Expected output:

```
try.csv:,410,30151010,K,5001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,512
try.csv:,652,20151010,K,5001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,41
try.csv:,109,30151010,R,5005,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,455
```

I am very new to Perl and shell. I'm searching in the CSV files.

Comment: `perl -pe's/^try.csv:\K/,/'`

Comment: `sed 's/^[^:]*:/&,/'`

Comment: sed works perfectly fine. thanks. CWLiu can you explain this to me how is this works ?

Comment: @CWLiu: `sed 's/^[^:]*:/&,/'` is the same as `sed 's/:/&,/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may insert a comma by using `sed`,

```
$ grep --color -EH "^([^,]*\,){3}5" try.csv | sed 's/:/&,/'
```

`s/:/&,/`: the the special character & in the replacement refers to that portion of the string which matched. And you may add a comma behind `&` to meet your requirement.

Comment: There's no need to anchor the regex and match everything up to the first colon. `/:/` on its own will match the first colon, and `sed 's/:/&,/'` is sufficient.